# Return html from controller action in Zend

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, load

i have a structure like so:

modules -> Controllers -> Amodule -> IndexController

there i have an action which is called:

```
public function getTemplateAction(){
   ... //1) load html file
       //2) return html
}
```

this function is called from javascript with get via the url: baseUrl+'/Amodule/index/get-template/viewid/3.

I would like based on the viewid to return an html template, where should i put the .html file and how can i load it in Zend? i tried

```
this->partial('thetemplate.html');
```

and putting the html file in Amodule folder but didnt work.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added another folder at the same level as controller called it views/scripts and in there i created the partial. Then from the view i load the partial as:

```
<?php  echo $this->partial('_partialName.phtml', array(
       var1 => value1,
       var2 => value2
       /*... vars to pass in the partial*/
));?>
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution is to have your html files in a dedicated folder at the root of your project and output the file with readfile :

```
public function getTemplateAction() {
    readfile(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../templates/thetemplate.html');
    exit;
}
```